# Differences between inner join and where in (select...)

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

What is the difference between the following 2 Query?

select * from DB_TABLE1
Inner join DB_TABLE2 ON DB_TABLE1.ID = DB_TABLE2.ID

select * from DB_TABLE1
Where ID in (select ID from DB_TABLE2)

Maybe the question is stupid, I'm a newbie to queries...
Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: Your question had already been asked (and answered) on SO before: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533891/difference-between-inner-join-and-where-in-select-join-sql-statement#:~:text=4%20Answers&text=One%20difference%20is%20that%20the,exact%20intent%20of%20the%20query. and Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: @GoodJuJu Eh? They are totally different questions you have linked to.

Comment: The previous posts I linked to are: `Difference between inner join and where in select join SQL statement`  and `INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause`.  I would say they are very similar to your question, `Differences between inner join and where in (select…)`

Comment: @GoodJuJu You need to read the question, not just the (sometimes) innapropriate title ;-)

Answer (score 2):

These are two very different queries.

In your first, you are `joining` the tables using a `key` column in either, and then `selecting` all columns from `both` tables.

For each row in your `left` table, you are matching `all` rows in the `right` table, so if Table1 has 1 row with an ID of 1 and Table2 has 2 rows with an ID of 1, you will get 2 rows.

Conversly, your second query is selecting *only* the columns from Table1 and `filtering` out rows where the ID is not in Table2. you only get columns from Table1 and rows are never duplicated, only filtered out.

Comment: Thank you so much, originally my problem arose precisely for this reason and, I wanted to understand if it was actually due to what you indicated.

Comment: Hey, if this helped you out, feel free to accept the answer :-())

Answer (score 1):

These are called **JOIN** and **subquery** respectively. You can check this out by using [this simple explanation](https://learnsql.com/blog/subquery-vs-join/).

Comment: Thank you for the complete article linked.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please upvote my answer if it was useful for you?